# SSH2 PHP exec remote

Tags: php, ssh2

I have a game server compilation process in PHP but the exec function is turned off on my hosting. Can we compile it from the ssh2 machine and upload it to the panel? I want to shoot remotely with ssh2 php execLyrics distribution will come for the amxmodx version php panel will be compiled remotely via ssh2 and uploaded to the panel.

```
<?php
    $eklentikelime = array(
        "\"(.*)rcon_password(.*)\"","\"(.*)connect (.*)\""
    );
    
    $ssh2 = new ogcp_ssh2();
if(isset($_GET["Yukle"])) {
        if($ssh2->ConnectwAuth($serverinfo["MachIP"],(int)$serverinfo["MachPort"],$serverinfo["MachUser"],$serverinfo["MachPass"])) {   
            if($_FILES['Filedata']['error'] == 0 && pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name'])['extension'] == "sma") {
                //move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], );
                $eskiad = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
                $yeniad2  = tr_karakter($eskiad);
                $yeniadxd = filtre_sma($yeniad2);
                $yeniad4  = bosluk_sil($yeniadxd);
                $yeniad4  = mb_strtolower($yeniad4);
                $yeniad3  = preg_replace("/\./", "", $serverinfo["ServerIP"]).'_'.$yeniad4;
                $_FILES['Filedata']['name'] = $yeniad3;
                $main_name = explode('.',$_FILES["Filedata"]["name"])[0];
                $filecontent = file_get_contents($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']);
                $durum = 2;
                foreach($eklentikelime as $kelime) {
                    preg_match('/'.$kelime.'/i',$filecontent,$matches);
                    if(count($matches) > 0) { $durum = 0; break; }
                }
                if($durum == 2) {
                    $smafile = "./".$main_name.".sma";
                    file_put_contents("./__hcsgp_system/compiler/".$main_name.".sma", $filecontent);
                    $output = exec("cd ./__hcsgp_system/compiler; ./amxxpc {$smafile} -o".$main_name.".amxx >> ".$main_name.'.log');
                    if(file_exists("./__hcsgp_system/compiler/".$main_name.".amxx")) {
                        $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'] = "./__hcsgp_system/compiler/".$main_name.".amxx";
                        $_FILES['Filedata']['name'] = $main_name.".amxx";
                        $log = file_get_contents('./__hcsgp_system/compiler/'.$main_name.'.log');
                            
                        if ( $ssh2->SFTP_UploadFile($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'],$serverinfo["ServerPath"]."/cstrike/addons/amxmodx/plugins/".$_FILES['Filedata']['name']) ) {
                
                        //  $log = implode("\n",array_slice(explode("\n",$log), 3, -3));
                            
                        @file_put_contents($ssh2->SFTP_FileLink($serverinfo["ServerPath"]."/cstrike/addons/amxmodx/configs/plugins-panel.ini"), @file_get_contents($ssh2->SFTP_FileLink($serverinfo["ServerPath"]."/cstrike/addons/amxmodx/configs/plugins-panel.ini"))."\r\n".$_FILES['Filedata']['name']."");

                            $_SESSION['WebFTPMesaj'] = '<strong>İşlem Başarılı!</strong><br/>Eklenti plugins-panel.ini\'ye eklenmiştir!<br/>Eklenti adı: <h7 style="color:#428bca;"> '.$main_name.'.amxx </br><h4>Çıktısı</h4><pre style="background-color:black; color: #adff2f;">'.$log.'</pre></div>';
                            
                        } else {
                            $_SESSION['WebFTPMesaj'] = '<div class="alert alert-warning"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>İşlem Başarısız!</strong><br/>Eklenti sunucuya aktarılamadı!</div>';
                        }

                        unlink("./__hcsgp_system/compiler/".$main_name.".amxx");
                    } else {
                        
                    $_SESSION['WebFTPMesaj'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Hatalı Eklenti!</strong><br/>'.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'].' isimli Eklenti derlenemedi!<br/><h4>Eklenti Çıktısı</h4><br/><pre style="background-color:black; color: #adff2f;">'.$log.'</pre></div>';   
                        unlink("./__hcsgp_system/compiler/".$main_name.".sma"); 
                        unlink('./__hcsgp_system/compiler/'.$main_name.'.log');
                    }

                    //unlink("./__hcsgp_system/compiler/".$main_name.".sma");
                unlink('./__hcsgp_system/compiler/'.$main_name.'.log');
                } else {
                        $_SESSION['WebFTPMesaj'] = '<div class="alert alert-warning"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>İşlem Başarısız!</strong><br/>Eklentide yasaklanmış komut bulundu!</div>';
                        $durum = -1;
                }
            }else {
            $_SESSION['WebFTPMesaj'] = "Dosya Uzantısına izin verilmiyor! sadece .sma !";

        }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['WebFTPMesaj'] = "Sunucu Ile Baglanti Kurulamadı";

        }
    }

?>

<script src="<?php echo $page->LoadTheme_File('skynlexx/js/uploadifive/jquery.min.js');?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $page->LoadTheme_File('skynlexx/js/uploadifive/jquery.uploadifive.js');?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $page->LoadTheme_File('skynlexx/js/uploadifive/uploadifive.css');?>">
<style type="text/css">
#queue {
    color: #fff !important;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0 3px 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
.uploadifive-queue-item {
    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #007bff 5%, #31353d 120%);
}
</style>

<div id='gelenveri'></div>


                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <div>
                <center>
                <b><font size="3">Eklenti Yuklenecek IP : <?php echo $serverinfo["ServerIP"]; ?> </font></b>
                 </br>
                 <b><font size="3">Sadece <font color="red">.sma</font> dosyası kabul edilir</font></b>
                 </br>
                 <b><font size="2">Sma dosyalarında<font color="red"> motd_write, connect, bind</font> komutu kullanınırsa hata verecektir.</font></b>
                 </div>
                 </div>



    <form>
    
                  <table style="width: 100%;" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr align="center">
                   <td colspan="2"><b>Extra eklenti yükleme (sma)<br>
                   Yüklediğiniz eklentileri <a href="Dosya_Duzenle.html&ID=15"><u>plugins-panel.ini</u></a> Sayfasında bulabilirsiniz.
                   </b></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        
                        <td align="center">
                       <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
                        </td>
                      </tr> 
                                                 
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
    
    <div id="queue"></div>
    </form>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
        <?php $timestamp = time(); ?>
            $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
                'fileTypeExts'     : '*.sma;',
                'auto'             : true,
                'formData'         : {
                                       'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                                       'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                                     },
                'queueID'          : 'queue',
                'uploadScript'     : '<?=$page->CreatePageLink($cur_page,"Yukle");?>',
                'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) {
                var skynlexx = 'skymesaj.php?skynlexx=1';
                $.get(skynlexx,function (msg){
                    Swal.fire({
                    title: "<b>Sonuç</b>", 
                    html: msg,  
                    });
                    });
                }
            });
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilation requires you to have a server with the same settings to work. I think it's easier for you to try and ask your hosting admin about the move or just move to a dedicated server and then become root.

Remembering that "with great power comes great responsibility".

Comment: I have a server, I want to activate this process by installing ssh2 and php on the linux server and installing it from the linux server to the linux server connected to the panel.

Comment: if you are the administrator of your server, check the php.ini file and look for the line that contains *disable_functions*, it is quite possible that it is configured with exec, just remove and reload the service.